# How to capitalize only the first letter in the string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Hi i have a variable like below,

```
const str = 'passed'
```

now i want to capitalize only the first letter of the string. i can do it like below

```
const str2 = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
```

but is there any other better way to do the same using javascript?

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Lots of different approaches in that mentioned duplicate - which you could have easily found yourself btw., by just typing your chosen question title into Google verbatim.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform